# BigQuery: Get latest row in a table only if a field has a specific value

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's assume that we have a table in BigQuery with the following data:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD
  x  |   y  |  1   |   5
  x  |   y  |  0   |   6
  k  |   z  |  1   |   4
```

ColA, ColB are String, ColC is Integer and ColD timestamp.

I need to get the latest row (`LAST(ColD)`) for each unique value of ColA **only if** ColC is equal to 1. That is, in the above table, the result of the query should be:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD
  k  |   z  |  1   |   4
```

Rows 1 and 2 should not be included in the results, since for `ColA=x` the last entry in the table (Row 2) had `ColC=0`.

I have tried various queries using aggregate functions (e.g. MAX, LAST) in combination with subqueries but was not able to reach to the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper name for the analytic function in SQL Standard is `FIRST_VALUE`. `FIRST` is aggregation function in BigQuery

So first you obtain the last ColC for each ColA ordered by the timestamp

```
SELECT
  ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  time,
  FIRST_VALUE(ColC) OVER (PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY time DESC) AS last_Col_C
FROM (
  SELECT
    'x' AS ColA,
    'y' AS ColB,
    1 AS ColC,
    5 AS time),
  (
  SELECT
    'x' AS ColA,
    'y' AS ColB,
    0 AS ColC,
    6 AS time),
  (
  SELECT
    'k' AS ColA,
    'z' AS ColB,
    1 AS ColC,
    4 AS time)
```

Then you further select what interests you, final query looks like:

```
SELECT
  ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  time
FROM (
--the above query here--)
    where last_Col_C=1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are totally right, this is what I needed.