# How to get summarized and ranked list of data in BigQuery - summarize many rows into 1 based on rank

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, grafana

I have a BigQuery view (`flow_test_metrics_level_1_moving_average`) that keeps track of the average failure rate for different tests.

```
SELECT test, commit_date2, result2, AVG(result2)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY test
    ORDER BY commit_date2
    ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS avg_result
FROM `data.dev_src_flow_test_metrics.flow_test_metrics_level_1`
ORDER BY test
```

Here are some rows returned from this view:

[image]

This is working and I can visualize the data for each test in Grafana like this:

[image]

I would like to create a new visualization where I get a summarized and ranked list of tests with the highest failure rate, based on the latest commit date (`commit_date2` field) for each test. Not all tests will have the same commit date values.

`Test1` might have a latest commit date of Jan 1 where the average pass rate was 0.90.

`Test2` might have a latest commit date of Jan 2 where the average pass rate was 0.80.

`Test3` might have a latest commit date of Jan 3 where the average pass rate was 0.85.

I would like to create a new view showing the ranking as follows (from lowest pass rate to highest):

`Test2` (0.80)

`Test3` (0.85)

`Test1` (0.90)

I'd like to create a BigQuery view / table that creates this ranked list and only uses the latest commit date of each test.

I tried the following BigQuery view but I'm getting ALL test rows returned instead of just the latest ones for each test based on the commit date

```
SELECT test, avg_result, commit_date2,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY test ORDER BY avg_result desc) AS RANK
FROM `data.dev_src_flow_test_metrics.flow_test_metrics_level_1_moving_average`

ORDER BY commit_date2 desc
```

But this returns ALL the rows with their rank. I only want the last rows of each test, based on the latest commit date for each test.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this by splitting up the problem into 2 parts

1. find the latest commit date of each test
2. narrow down the result by using a where clause based on the latest commit date of each test

Got help from this SO answer: [BigQuery: Get latest row in a table only if a field has a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31965053/5719544) that was doing something very similar

1. create query to get the latest commit date of each test - this will still output all rows but the latest commit date will be constant now for each test.

```
SELECT test, avg_result, commit_date2,
  FIRST_VALUE(commit_date2) OVER (PARTITION BY test ORDER BY commit_date2 DESC) as latest_commit_date
FROM `data.dev_src_flow_test_metrics.flow_test_metrics_level_1_moving_average`
```

[image]

2. use the query from 1) as sub-query where you can narrow the result to match each test name, so there's only 1 record per test returned

```
SELECT test, avg_result, commit_date2
from (
SELECT test, avg_result, commit_date2,
  FIRST_VALUE(commit_date2) OVER (PARTITION BY test ORDER BY commit_date2 DESC) as latest_commit_date
FROM `data.dev_src_flow_test_metrics.flow_test_metrics_level_1_moving_average`
)
WHERE commit_date2 = latest_commit_date
```

Now we get a summary of 1 record per test with the latest commit date and showing the average result

[image]